# Using QGIS advancedpythonfieldcalculator from Python console

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-python-console, advanced-python-field-calculator

I'm trying to use the Advanced Python field calculator in a script like so:

```py
processing.runalg('qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator', output_layer, 'Latitude', 1, 12, 5, '', '$y', output_layer2)
```

Not sure exactly how to put the arguments

```
ALGORITHM: Advanced Python field calculator
INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
FIELD_NAME <ParameterString>
FIELD_TYPE <ParameterSelection>
FIELD_LENGTH <ParameterNumber>
FIELD_PRECISION <ParameterNumber>
GLOBAL <ParameterString>
FORMULA <ParameterString>
OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>
```

Particularly, the GLOBAL and FORMULA args. Docs don't show much on this..
I'm getting a return of an empty file (i.e. no points), but the attribute table has the new field name in it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When using the **Advanced Python Field Calculator**, you need to explicity define the [QgsGeometry functions](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html), which in the normal Field Calculator is usually done for you.

E.g.

- Field Calculator: `$y`
- Advanced Python Field Calculator: `$geom.centroid().asPoint().y()`

So you can replace the `$y` expression in your algorithm with the one mentioned. Also, you need to add `value =` in the *Formula* parameter. Therefore, your algorithm should look like:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:advancedpythonfieldcalculator', output_layer, 'Latitude', 1, 12, 5, "", "value = $geom.centroid().asPoint().y()", output_layer2)
```